# Magento 2 : How to change html/css classes of onepage checkout in custom theme

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, onepage-checkout

I'm creating a new theme from scratch, I would like to change the html code of the **checkout/#shipping** page. However, the template (**Magento_Checkout/onpage.phtml**) containing the html code that I would like to change contains mostly javascript.

I couldn't figure out where the html code in this template is located. Is it defined in a .js file?

What is the best way to modify the html classes of the elements in this template and change its layout?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

All templates you want to override are in
`\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template`.

**EDIT:**
To find `.html` template and `.js` component: first you need to find the `.html` template, which is pretty easy. You inspect element, and you search in above folder for this elements. When you have the name of the template you go to `checkout_index_index.xml` file, which define whole layout for checkout page.
For example:
You inspect 'Order summary' and you realized that this element has class name `opc-block-summary`, so you search for this class in above folder. Div with this class is in `web/template/summary.html`. When you have name of this template you can search for it in `checkout_index_index.xml`. Template file is specify by
`<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary</item>`, notice that there is no `.html`. And you also skip `web/template`. So `Magento_Checkout/summary` means module-checkout `/view/frontend/web/template/summary.html`.
**Summarizing** :
`<item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary</item>` tells You about template file, and
`<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary</item>` tells You about Js file.

You have to notice, that M2 uses knockout JS to render elements on checkout.

Comment: Thanks, if we want to move some container how can we proceed? These are not block I guess so how to move elements?

Comment: Could you specify which block/container you want to move? and where?

Comment: Ok I understood how to move the elements, is there a way to easily find the JS templates present in the page?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm going the right way, so the answer is no we can't find easily template like normal template with hints